# i am trying to fetch a Post request but im not getting any value and my app stuck on (loading menu...) i don't know what to do

Tags: json, http-post, react-native

**this is my code**
so in the fetch() function i am getting the response but i am nit getting any object or values and my app stuck at (loading view...) function

```
var REQUEST_URL = 'http://awaissaleem.com/json/api.php';

class test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    menu: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    menu : 'menu',
    active : '1',
  })
}).then((response) => response.text())
.then((responseData) => {
    this.setState({
          menu: responseData.Response,
      }); 
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.warn('error',error);
})
.done();
  }

 render() {
    if (!this.state.menu) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    var menus = this.state.menu[0];
    console.log('menus',menus);
    return this.renderMovie(menus);
  }

  renderLoadingView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Loading menu...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderMovie(menus) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{menus.menu_type}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.year}>{menus.menu_no}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

so please point me out where i am missing something..

Comment: i am new on stack overflow so please don't mind if i didn't ask the question in the right manner

Comment: React side of code looks good to me. You should check php side of code.

Comment: i am using postman for the json response testing. i am getting the response in postman but not in react @BilalBudhani

Comment: Have you tried debugging in chrome to ensure a) the data is coming down from the server correctly, and b) `responseData` is containing the data you think it should have?